# How do I remove portions of a video that are unchanged?

Tags: video-editing

I have about 36 hours of screen capture of computer usage for internal training purposes.

It would be very useful if I was able to strip out the sometimes-minutes-long idle periods.

I'd be satisfied with automatically cropping them out, but inserting a transition would be nifty.

Is there an automated tool that can perform this task without me having to go through 36 hours of video?

Video Format: Fairly Raw AVI

Answer (score 2):

Well... [NCH has Video Surveillance software](http://www.nchsoftware.com/surveillance/index.html) that advertises...

> Find and play surveillance recordings ordered by camera, date, duration and motion detected

[Ocularis PS](http://www.onssi.com/products/ocularis-ps) is a comprehensive surveillance system solution that includes video analytics that can be set to review video for movement... but would probably be quite expensive for just this one task.

[Gotcha](http://www.gotchanow.com/) is a small program that can be used to view live or recorded video and includes a motion detection feature.

[ContaCam](http://www.contaware.com/content/view/44/46/) is a free solution that offers the ability to review existing movies and motion detection, but I don't know if you can combine them both.  But, as it is a free option, it's definitely worth looking at.

Otherwise, most solutions offer motion detection as a feature of what is recorded by the software, as opposed to monitoring an existing recording.

Then again, you could always just open the raw video in an editor, and play it at a high speed, looking for movement.  When you see it, you pause, back up a little, and tag those sections.

Comment: NCH seems *slightly* dodgy [http://superuser.com/questions/99492/is-software-from-nch-software-safe](according to the answers to this question). If you do install their software, keep an eye out for toolbars and things.